# Reinstalling Orange Add-on over again

Tags: orange, image, association-rules, education, bioinformatics

After I upgraded to the latest orange version (3.36.2), I observed that whenever I install an add-on, for instance, Bioinformatics, when I close and reopen the orange software, all the new add-ons are no longer there. This makes me reinstall them again.
Please kindly look into this.
Thank you